# Matlab equivalent of R's nested way of accessing logical array

Tags: r, matlab

In `R` one can set the value of several logical array elements say `a` only if those elements are `true`. e.g.

```
a[a][b]<-FALSE
```

Here, `b` is another logical array.

Is there an equivalent way for `Matlab`? Say something like this(although this doesn't work):

```
a(a)(b) = false;
```

Edit: What I want to do?
Say I have a logical array `a` and another array `b` equal in length to the number of `true` elements in `a`. So I wish to put all those `true` element index of `a` which are also `true` for `b` to `false`.

Comment: "That element"... what element?

Comment: @EitanT, I hope its clear now?

Comment: Not entirely. What is `b`?

Comment: @EitanT, now? Sorry I forgot about that.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand the logic. What do you want to do? Set all `true` elements in `a` to `b`?

Comment: @EitanT, I have added a brief explanation of what I am trying to do. I hope it helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course. The expression `a(a == true)` (or shorter `a(a)`) find all the elements in `a` that equal `true` (logical "1"). The values that you want to assign to them equal:

```
a(a) = a(a) & ~b;
```

or

```
a(a) = xor(a(a), b);
```

Comment: `b` is not of same length as `a`. Rather `b` is equal in length to number of true values in `a`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. `R` made me think in the wrong direction. I was thinking in terms of temporary arrays and of course `find`.